# Multiple action in one jsp form

Tags: java, jsp, notifications, jakarta-mail

I want my system to notify the admin whenever there is an applicant applying the job through the system. Is it possible to have multiple action in one jsp form? One goes to servlet, another one calls another class to notify the admin via java mail. Or i need to create another submit button that can notify the admin? if so how can i do that with the class below? or is there any way to notify the admin via email?

this is the code to sendemail

```
package SendEmail;

import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
public class EmailSend {

public static void main(String args[]){
    try{
        String host ="smtp.gmail.com" ;
        String user = "myemail";
        String pass = "x";
        String to = "anotheremail";
        String from = "myemail";
        String subject = "New Application Have Arrived";
        String messageText = "Please Check Career Website";
        boolean sessionDebug = false;

        Properties props = System.getProperties();

        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");

        java.security.Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        mailSession.setDebug(sessionDebug);
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)}; //address of sender
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address); //receiver to email
        msg.setSubject(subject); msg.setSentDate(new Date()); //message send date
        msg.setText(messageText); //actual message

       Transport transport=mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
       transport.connect(host, user, pass);
       transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
       transport.close();
       System.out.println("Message send successfully");
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: why you want to have multiple actions from JSP? is there any specific requirement for you ?. If you want to send multiple notifications you can do it from your server. Call `servlet` which will create instances for the classes to perform some operations that you need, for example: saving details(SaveDetails.java), sending mails(Mail.java), performing other operations (Other.java), etc.

Comment: @Srinu i got the solution just now and  i applied the try{} in the servlet :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did it like this so that i dont have to do two action on my jsp form haha im dumb

```
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;

@WebServlet("/uploadServlet")
@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 16177215)

public class UploadFileController extends HttpServlet 
{
public static String user= "root";
public static String password = "x";
public static Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException{
    Connection conn=null;
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kps","root","X");
        System.out.println("Connected");
    }catch(SQLException e){System.err.println(e);}

    return conn;
}
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException 
{
            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

            InputStream inputStream = null;

            Random rand = new Random();
            int  n = rand.nextInt(9999) + 1;
            String idTemp=(String.valueOf(n));


            String title=(request.getParameter("title"));
            Part filePart = request.getPart("file_uploaded");

            if (filePart != null) 
            {
                System.out.println(filePart.getName());
                System.out.println(filePart.getSize());
                System.out.println(filePart.getContentType());

                inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
            }

            try 
            {
                Connection conn = UploadFileController.getConnection();
                //Connection conn= dbconn.Connection();

                String sql = "INSERT INTO files (id, title, file) values (?, ?, ?)";
                PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                statement.setString(1, idTemp);
                statement.setString(2, title);

                if (inputStream != null) 
                {
                    statement.setBinaryStream(3, inputStream, (int) filePart.getSize());
                }

                int row = statement.executeUpdate();
                if (row > 0) 
                {
                    try{
                        String host ="smtp.gmail.com" ;
                        String user = "email";
                        String pass = "password";
                        String to = "another email";
                        String from = "email";
                        String subject = "New Application Have Arrived";
                        String messageText = "Please Check Career Website";
                        boolean sessionDebug = false;

                        Properties props = System.getProperties();

                        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
                        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
                        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
                        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");

                        java.security.Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
                        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
                        mailSession.setDebug(sessionDebug);
                        Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
                        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
                        InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)}; //address of sender
                        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address); //receiver to email
                        msg.setSubject(subject); msg.setSentDate(new Date()); //message send date
                        msg.setText(messageText); //actual message

                       Transport transport=mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
                       transport.connect(host, user, pass);
                       transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
                       transport.close();
                       System.out.println("Message send successfully");
                    }catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        System.out.println(ex);
                    }
                    out.println("File uploaded!!!");

                    conn.close();

                    RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("try.jsp");
                    rs.include(request, response);
                }
                else
                {
                    out.println("Couldn't upload your file!!!");

                    conn.close();

                    RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("error.jsp");
                    rs.include(request, response);
                }    

            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();
            } 
}   
}
```

so yeah i asked stupid question, forgive me im a newbie